# Failing to add objects to an empty array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

So I have an empty array and I want to add objects with values determined on runtime. I came up with this code:

```js
var res = []; //the result array which needs to be populated
var rn = Math.random() * 5;
var value1 = rn * 75,
  value2 = rn * 27.91;
let galf = {
  type: rn;
  v1l: Math.floor(value1 / 7);
  v2r: value2 % 7;
}
res.push(galf);
console.log(res)
```

Now it appears that my declaration of the galf object is erratic. If I comment out this declaration, then the code runs fine.

How do I properly add objects to the array when values of the object are to be determined at runtime?

Comment: I made you a snippet. The error it throws is very useful. As LeeLenalee said `You shouldnt use ; in an object, to add more fields you need to use the , to separate fields`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldnt use `;` in an object, to add more fields you need to use the `,` to seperate fields

```js
var res = []; //the result array which needs to be populated
var rn = Math.random() * 5;
var value1 = rn * 75,
  value2 = rn * 27.91;

let galf = {
  type: rn,
  v1l: Math.floor(value1 / 7),
  v2r: value2 % 7,
}

res.push(galf);

console.log(res)
```

Comment: Really worth an answer?

Comment: Really worth the downvote :), we all make mistakes would be glad if I made them someone would point them out

Comment: Add the `You shouldnt use ; in an object, to add more fields you need to use the , to seperate fields` as a comment and vote to close as typo type would be the correct course of action here

Comment: @mplungjan well and if it wasn't a typo? maybe user just didn't know the syntax?

Comment: Typo-type - come on allow op to delete this question

Comment: it's not my answer :D

Comment: @FlashThunder yes indeed. That was the case. It's not that I typed ; as a typo, I actually didn't _know_ that one ought to contend with commas only in a js object.